# Binding ProgressBar inside ListView to a nested property in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, progress-bar

I've been trying to bind the ProgressBar value inside a ListView item (custom control) to a subproperty (DownloadProgress) of each item inside the ObservableCollection property (VideoDisplayExternals) I have in my VM. My purpose for this is so that I can update the value of the ProgressBar while I'm downloading each video also inside each item.

Below is code for when I'm downloading. This is in a method in my VM.

```
foreach (VideoDisplayExternal videoDisplayExternal in VideoDisplayExternals)
            {
                Video video = videoDisplayExternal.Video;

                var streamInfo = videoDisplayExternal.SelectedStream;
                string fileName = $"{video.Title}.{streamInfo.Container}";
                string downloadPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(playlistFolderPath, fileName);

                // this works (progress value inside VideoDisplayExternal item is changed) but ProgressBar isn't updated                
                CurrentlyDownloadingVideoDisplayExternal = videoDisplayExternal;
                var progressHandler = new Progress<double>(ShowDownloadProgress);

                // download video
                await youtube.Videos.Streams.DownloadAsync(streamInfo, downloadPath, progressHandler);
                CurrentlyDownloadingVideoDisplayExternal = null;                
            }
```

These are my VM properties:

```
public ObservableCollection<VideoDisplayExternal> VideoDisplayExternals { get; set; }

private VideoDisplayExternal currentlyDownloadingVideoDisplayExternal;
public VideoDisplayExternal CurrentlyDownloadingVideoDisplayExternal
        {   
            get { return currentlyDownloadingVideoDisplayExternal; }
            set
            {
                currentlyDownloadingVideoDisplayExternal = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentlyDownloadingVideoDisplayExternal");
            }
        }
```

These are my models:

```
public class VideoDisplayExternal   
    {
        public bool IsCheckBoxChecked { get; set; }
        public Video Video { get; set; }
        public List<YoutubeExplode.Videos.Streams.MuxedStreamInfo> Streams { get; set; }
        public YoutubeExplode.Videos.Streams.MuxedStreamInfo SelectedStream { get; set; }
        public double DownloadProgress { get; set; }
    }

public class Video
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int VideoDownloadId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string ThumbnailUrl { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan? Duration { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is my ProgressBar binding (note that this is inside a UserControl thats' inside a ListView):

```
<ProgressBar Grid.Row="1"
                         Margin="10"
                         Maximum="100"
                         Minimum="0"
                         Value="{Binding DownloadProgress, Mode=OneWay, 
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I have never been so confused in my life so I hope some of you can guide me towards finding a solution for this. The ProgressBar doesn't seem to update at all although the DownloadProgress of each VideoDisplayExternal does change and even reaches 100 after downloading.

Comment: It seems that you haven't implemented INotifyPropertyChanged for VideoDisplayExternal, especially DownloadProgress. BTW `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in ProgressBar.Value's binding is unncessary.

Comment: Thanks! It works now. I can't believe it was that simple.